# Storing and sorting images

Tags: php, mysql, image, search, storage

What is the best way to store lots of images on my website?

I appreciate this is an open question, however, I am concerned with performance issues if any.

When I upload files to my site should I store them all in the same directory and give them a random filename and store that name in the database along with the URL.

Or

Should I break the photos down into `[year]/[month]` directories?

Is there a standard way to store lots of photos? IF the latter is the better option, how can I automatically move the files into their respective folders?

Comment: There is not really a best way, the best way to store pictures is so you can easely refind pictures later... So you need to figure out a filestrcuture yourself..

Comment: Is there any benefit to storing them in separate directories based on date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store you photos in the Static Content of your Web server and store their `path, created date, created by` in the table.
When the rows increase, you can partition the table on the basis of `createddate`.